# How to filter a wave file to remove background noise?

Tags: python, arduino, wav

I have used Arduino rp2040 connect to record a wave file at a frequency of 3k Hz. But there is much noise in the audio file.
This is the code that I have used to filter the audio-

```
from scipy.signal import lfilter, butter
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np

lowcut = 2000.0
highcut = 4000.0


def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band', fs=fs)
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

def bandpass_filter(buffer):
    return butter_bandpass_filter(buffer, lowcut, highcut, sr, order=6)


sr, data = wavfile.read('3000.wav')
filtered = np.array(bandpass_filter(data).astype(np.int16))
wavfile.write('3000_filter.wav', sr, filtered)
```

This code is giving me this error:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
filtered = np.array(bandpass_filter(data).astype(np.int16))
```

The filtered file has no sound, what can be the reason for this and please explain what can be done?

Comment: You're possibly hitting some `np.nan` or `np.inf` values, I would remove the `astype(np.int16)` and inspect the result. Also, have you inspected the loaded `data` array to make sure it looks right? According to NumPy's docs, this particular warning could be platform dependent

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the division by `nyq`. The low frequency and high frequency passed to the `butter` function should be in the range from `0` to `0.5*sr` but not normalized. The following code works

```py
from scipy.signal import lfilter, butter
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np

lowcut = 100.0
highcut = 1000.0


def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter(order, [lowcut, highcut], btype='band', fs=fs)
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

def bandpass_filter(buffer):
    return butter_bandpass_filter(buffer, lowcut, highcut, sr, order=6)


sr, data = wavfile.read('3000.wav')
filtered = np.array(bandpass_filter(data).astype(np.int16))
wavfile.write('3000_filter.wav', sr, filtered)
```

Note: you need the low frequencies to stay in order to filter the noise (high frequencies)